# Python: how to put " " on every string from a list

Tags: python

I have a list of all possible combinations of a 4-digit number and I want to put them in possible_comb = [...]

But the list does not have any separator like a comma for example and it does not have the ".." per 4 digit number.

Example:

#This is my list

```
list = [ 0000 0001 0002 0003...9999] # no (,) and (")
```

#expected

```
list = ["0000", "0001", "0002",..."9999"]
```

Putting " and , manually is hellish. How to put "..." and , on every string from the list? Or are there any other ways to list all possible 4 digit numbers and put it in a list as a string?Thanks.

Comment: The "my list" you posted is not legal Python syntax.  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm trying to make a code where I iterate one 4-digit number at a time from the list = [0000...9999]

Such as that the output will be "0000" and then by looping, the next output will be "0001" and so on. 

But the problem is my list is not in string format and does not have commas,just spaces in between..

This is the expected list, 
list = ["0000", "0001",... "9999"]

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do. Are you starting out with a list in Python? Are you starting with a file? You can't "add" commas to a Python list, that's just part of how they're represented on screen. Similarly, quotes just mean the value is a string, as opposed to an int. I think you'll probably want the `range()` function, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a list like this with a list comprehension by converting integers to strings and using [`zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to pad with zeros:

```
l = [str(n).zfill(4) for n in range(10000)]
```

`l` will be:

```
['0000',
 '0001',
 '0002',
 '0003',
 '0004',
 '0005',
 ...
 '9999'
 ]
```

Depending on how you are using it you might be better off with a generator expression.

```
l = (str(n).zfill(4) for n in range(10000))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but it should work (given `x` is your input string that looks like a list):

```
x = "[0000 0001 0002 0003]"
final_list = []
digit = ""

for i in x[1:]:
    if i.isdigit():
        digit += i
    else:
        final_list.append(digit)
        digit = ""

# print(final_list)
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks! This worked as well but there's one issue. The output does not print out the last string in the list.

Comment: Whoops, a slight bug. I fixed it in the answer above. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you want to convert integer to string type then this will do the job:

```
 a = [ 0000 ,0001 ,0002, 0003,...9999]
 a = list(map(str,a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert all the integers in your list to strings. Try this:

```
for i in list:
    list[i] = str(list[i])
```

Or if you want to generate all the combinations:

```
list = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):
            for l in range(10):
                list.append(str(1000*i + 100*j + 10*k + l))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method to automatically add the quotations and commas:

```
lst_str = str(your_list)
lst_final = lst.split(" ")
lst_final[0] = "0000"
lst_final[-1] = "9999"
```